# How to slice Rcpp NumericVector for elements 2 to 101?

Tags: rcpp

Hi I'm trying to slice Rcpp's NumericVector for elements 2 to 101

in R, I would do this:

```
array[2:101]
```

How do I do the same in RCpp?

I tried looking here: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/
But the resource has an example that lists all the elements using IntegerVector::create(). However, ::create() is limited by the number of elements. (in addition to being tedious). Any way to slice a vector given 2 indices?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is possible with *Rcpp*'s `Range` function. This generates the equivalent *C++* positional index sequence. e.g.

```
Rcpp::Range(0, 3)
```

would give:

```
0 1 2 3
```

Note: *C++* indices begin at 0 not 1!

Example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector subset_range(Rcpp::NumericVector x,
                                 int start = 1, int end = 100) {

  // Use the Range function to create a positional index sequence
  return x[Rcpp::Range(start, end)];
}

/***R
x = rnorm(101)

# Note: C++ indices start at 0 not 1!
all.equal(x[2:101], subset_range(x, 1, 100))
*/
```