# Subsetting NumericVector in Rcpp with multiple index ranges

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wish to subset a `NumericVector` in `Rcpp` using multiple index ranges. In `R` I would do this the following way:

```
b <- as.vector(seq(1:100))
c <- b[c(1:3,5:7,9:14)]
```

In `Rcpp` I have got the following to return values from a single set of range values:

```
cppFunction('NumericVector sub_vec(NumericVector my_vec, int low, int high) {
  return my_vec[my_vec > low & my_vec < high];
}')
sub_vec(b,1,3)
```

How can I modify this function to include multiple ranges like those shown in the above `R` example?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `c(1:3,5:7,9:14)` would be an `IntegerVector`. You can subset `NumericVector`s by `IntegerVector`s. Is your question how to create an `IntegerVector` like `c(1:3,5:7,9:14)` on the C++ side? If so, besides doing something manually like `IntegerVector::create(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)`, you might want to take a look at [this discussion on Rcpp-devel](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-January/007025.html)

Comment: @duckmayr Good find on the old `concat` post. Any interest (hint, hint) in brushing that up a Sugar function?

Comment: thanks for the reply @duckmayr. As a novice Rcpp user I will try and get my head round the primitive function shown on the link you've provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice Rcpp NumericVector for elements 2 to 101?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246200/how-to-slice-rcpp-numericvector-for-elements-2-to-101)

Comment: How did you solve the problem?