# selecting vector based on index in R vs rcpp

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

**EDIT**
After doing some more reading around C++, I managed to concise my question on what exactly I want to do. Basically, I have two vectors:

```
 my_vec <- c(270, 291, 330, 378)
 x <- 1:109
```

The four elements of `my_vec` correspond to 1st, 23rd, 61st and 109th element of vector `x` I want to write an Rcpp code that sums up x from 1:23rd value, 24th to 61st value and 62nd to 109th value as shown below in R:

```
 sum(x[1:22]) # 253
 sum(x[23:61]) # 1638
 sum(x[62:109]) # 4104
```

I wrote the following Rcpp code to this:

```
 library(Rcpp)

 cppFunction('

 List sum_calc(NumericVector x,
               NumericVector my_vec){

  int n = my_vec.size();  

  NumericVector sum_vec (n-1);

  double sum;

  int start_counter;
  int counter = 0;
  int start;
  int end;

  for(int i=0; i<(n-1); ++i){

      start = my_vec[i];
      end = my_vec[i + 1];

      double x_sum = 0;
      start_counter = start;

      while(start_counter <= end){      
            x_sum += x[counter];
            counter += 1;
            start_counter += 1;
      };

      sum_vec[i] = x_sum;
    };  

  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("sum_vec") = sum_vec);
}
')


 sum_calc(x, my_vec)

 $sum_vec
[1]  253 1700 4042
```

However only the first result is matching my output while the others two don't. I  think this is an index question but I don't know how to go about it. I have read C++ online and some material but still I cannot solve this. Where I am getting it wrong?

Comment: Such indexing questions have been asked and answered before. Try combining search terms in the search box as _e.g._ `[rcpp] index vector`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brcpp%5D+index+vector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246200/how-to-slice-rcpp-numericvector-for-elements-2-to-101

Comment: hello. thank you for your comments. I have edited my question to better reflect what is it I am doing. I am stuck on this problem for two days but I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: I still don't the question. If the two vectors are as given and especially `x <- 1:109`, who do you map `c(270, 291, 330, 378)` to `c(1, 23, 61, 109)` ?  Because if, say, I did ``c(270, 291, 330, 378) - 269` I would get `c(1, 22, 61, 109)`.  Which is off by one.  In short your question is still quite _minimal_ or _complete_ and _verifiable_.